# freebase city regions above neighborhood

Tags: freebase, mql

Using freebase how can I find say, all the burrows/subcities of NY? (queens, brooklyn, etc.)

And will it be similar to other cities?  Say if I want to know the subdivisions of Prague (Zizkov, Old Town, etc.) or Berlin, etc?

I've tried various combos but haven't hit one yet.

```
{
  "id": "/en/new_york",
  "guid": null,
  "name": null,
  "/location/location/containedby": [
  ],
  "/location/location/contains" : [],
  "/location/place_with_neighborhoods/neighborhoods": [
  ]
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone might be able to give a better answer but this will get major districts like in NY but probably not for smaller cities which are more like regions.

```
{
  "id": "/en/new_york",
  "guid": null,
  "name": null,
  "/location/location/containedby": [   
  ],
  "/location/location/contains" : [
    "name": null,
    "type": "/location/citytown"
  ]
}​
```

or to select multiple items that might be it

```
{
  "id": "/en/new_york",
  "guid": null,
  "name": null,
  "/location/location/containedby": [


  ],
  "/location/location/contains" : [
    "name": null,
    "type|=" : [
         "/location/citytown",
         "/location/neighborhood",
         "/location/administrative_division",
         "/location/de_borough",
         "/location/place_with_neighborhoods/neighborhoods"
       ]
  ]
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

The property /location/location/contains is the one that you want, but you're going to have two problems:

1. It's only sparsely populated
2. It has multiple levels of containment as a hack to work around API limitations

There's not much you can do about #1 unless you want to work on improving the data yourself. For #2, you can subtract the set of locations which are contained in another location in the "contains" set.